# How to capture at what time (in seconds) a video is played or paused in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, video-streaming, jquery-events

A web-page in HTML displays a video with controls. I want to capture when the video is paused by the user. jQuery `on()` method might be used for solving it.

I have tried using `$('#vid').on('pause', function(){/* do something */});` but it does not work properly

```
$(function() {
    var timer = 0;
    var vid_interval = setInterval(inc_timer, 1000);
    function inc_timer() {
        timer++;
    }

    $('#myvideo').on('pause', function(e) {
        clearInterval(vid_interval);
        $('body').append('<div>Pause: '+ timer +'</div>');
    });
    $('#myvideo').on('play', function(e) {
        vid_interval = setInterval(inc_timer, 1000);
        $('body').append('<div>Play: '+ timer +'</div>');
    });
});
```

The expected result was that it should show "Paused: 16", when it was paused at 16th second, and similarly for video-play, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
      if (event.key === "m") {  //press key m for marker
         video_duration= video_player.currentTime().toFixed(1);
         video_player.markers.add([{ time: video_duration, text: " "}]);
    }
    });
    },1000);
// onclick m the marker will be added on video play
```